# Azure API Management WSDL Import Failing on SOAP Encoding's Array Type

Tags: azure, wsdl, azure-api-management

I'm trying to create an API from a WSDL and currently getting this error back from Azure APIM during the import step:

```
Error: Parsing error : Line 17, position 22: Unable to import API from WSDL: Undefined
complexType 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is used as a base for 
complex type restriction.
```

I'm gathering that the `Array` type is not WSI-compliant, but would love insight as to how I can tinker with the WSDL to make it work? I don't own the service which generated the WSDL, but the WSDL hasn't changed since it was incepted and the provider has said it's okay for us to mess with it to get the Azure APIM import step to work. Just meaning, since Azure APIM's a passthrough what can I slice out of the WSDL which would still (a) let Azure APIM import it, and (b) allow the calls to successfully flow through Azure APIM at runtime?

I slimmed down the WSDL to this, but let me know if anything looks off as the original WSDL is ~5,500 lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<definitions 
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:s0="urn:ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:atls="http://tempuri.org/vc/atl/server/"
    targetNamespace="urn:ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
>
    <types>
        <s:schema targetNamespace="urn:ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <s:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            <s:complexType name="CMessage">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element name="Code" type="s:int"/>
                    <s:element name="Text" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="GetMessages_return_Array">
                <s:complexContent>
                    <s:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <s:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="s0:CMessage[]"/>
                    </s:restriction>
                </s:complexContent>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="MyHeader">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element name="m_SessionID" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:schema>
    </types>

    <message name="GetMessagesIn">
    </message>
    <message name="GetMessagesOut">
        <part name="return" type="s0:GetMessages_return_Array"/>
    </message>
    <message name="m_Header">
        <part name="m_Header" type="s0:MyHeader"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap">
        <operation name="GetMessages">
            <input message="s0:GetMessagesIn"/>
            <output message="s0:GetMessagesOut"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap" type="s0:ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
        <operation name="GetMessages">
            <soap:operation soapAction="#GetMessages" style="rpc"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:ChestersCopperpotsService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                <soap:header message="s0:m_Header" part="m_Header" use="encoded" namespace="urn:ChestersCopperpotsService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:ChestersCopperpotsService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
                <soap:header message="s0:m_Header" part="m_Header"  use="encoded" namespace="urn:ChestersCopperpotsService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="ChestersCopperpotsService">
        <port name="ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap" binding="s0:ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:80/ChestersCopperpots/ccSOAP.dll?Handler=Default"/>
        </port>
    </service>

</definitions>
```

Full message stack from Azure APIM is:

```
Informational: ParsingXMLStarted : Started parsing XML
Informational: ParsingXMLComplete : Completed parsing XML
Verbose: WsdlImportRuleVerifyWadl11Schema : WSDL validated against XML Schema
Informational: WsdlPrecheckComplete : Completed WSDL verification. WSDL is considered valid.
Informational: WsdlParsingStarted : Service : Endpoint :
Informational: WsdlIdentification : WsdlVersion: 'Wsdl11' TargetNamespace: 'urn:ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap'.
Informational: LoadedSchema : Target Namespace: 'urn:ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap'.
Informational: LoadedSchemas : Loaded '1' schemas.
Informational: LoadedTypes : Loaded '0' types.
Informational: LoadedMessages : Loaded '3' messages.
Informational: LoadedInterfaces : Loaded '1' interfaces.
Informational: LoadedBindings : Loaded '1' bindings.
Informational: LoadedServices : Loaded '1' services.
Informational: WsdlParsingComplete : Parsed 1 operations and 3 messages
Informational: ApiType : Creating SOAP Passthrough API
Informational: APICreated : Name : chesterscopperpotsservice Service Url: http://localhost:80/ChestersCopperpots/ccSOAP.dll?Handler=Default
Informational: XsdParsing : Starting to parse urn:ChestersCopperpotsServiceSoap
Error: Parsing error : Line 17, position 22: Unable to import API from WSDL: Undefined complexType 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is used as a base for complex type restriction.
```

Comment: That is not an api management issue, if you open your wsdl file with VS, you will get the same error.

Comment: @MohamadHaidar ... i think i made it clear in the post that the issue is with the XML since i've stated that i'm looking for a way to tweak the XML to get APIM to ingest it.

Answer (score 1):

my money is on this part (which in lack of row #, I suspect this is where the error get's triggered). The SOAP-to-REST transformation in APIM only supports "embedded" arrays, whereas yours is referring to another definition ("s0.CMessage" above). Try replacing that bit with

```xml
<s:complexType name="GetMessages_return_Array">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="ArrayOfCMessages" type="CMessage" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Comment: thanks @Marius i'll give it a try. i'm traveling at the moment, but it's definitely on my list for tomorrow.

Comment: hi @Marius, your change worked and allowed Azure APIM to import the WSDL. unfortunately it'll take me a while to see if that change is a non-breaking one as far as how things go at runtime, but i'm a step closer and i appreciate that.

i'm trying to figure out how to award you the bounty, but not sure (i've only offered one once before i think).

and for the `element` i used this (a slight tweak):
`<s:element name="CMessage" type="s0:CMessage" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />`

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, if this has helped so it might help others. Thank you.

Comment: hi @Marius ... unfortunately a bunch of other stuff broke after i edited the XSD. while your answer helped, it didn't fully solve my problem, unfortunately. seems that there may not have been a solution as we went through hoops to remove APIM from the workflow all together. sorry, i should have come back and provided some additional notes at the time.